# Why do the indices in object attributes for grouped_df start indexing at 0 instead of 1 as normally done in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Why do the indices in object attributes for a grouped data_frame/tbl start indexing at 0 instead of 1 as normally done in R? If I want to get the "correct" R indices I have to add 1. See code below for better understanding:

```
#Basic way of getting indices:
> which(mtcars$cyl==6)
[1]  1  2  4  6 10 11 30
#Group by and use attr(*, 'indices') to try and get indices:
> cars_group_by <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)
> attr(cars_group_by, 'indices')[2]
[[1]]
[1]  0  1  3  5  9 10 29
```

Comment: It is just an attribute.  If you need the indices, try `cars_group_by %>% group_indices(.)`

Comment: Because they're meant for internal use by the dplyr C++ code.